# PHPMailer emails not sending but there are no errors

Tags: php, email

I am using PHPMailer and using this PHP Code to send emails:

```
$email = new PHPMailer();

            while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
            {
                $email->AddAttachment( $result2["attachment"] , basename($result2["attachment"]) );
            }

            $email->From      = 'Integra Digital';
            $email->FromName  = $result["emailfrom"];
            $email->Subject   = $result["subject"];
            $email->Body      = $result["message"];

            $email->AddAddress($result["emailto"]);
            $email->IsHTML(true);

if(!$email->Send())
            {
                echo "<strong>Mailer Error: </strong>" . $email->ErrorInfo;
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<strong>Email sent to: </strong>' .implode(',',$emails_list). '<br/ >';
            }
```

$result["emailto"] is equal to a valid email address but i am not receiving the emails

any ideas?

Comment: where is the `$email->send()`?

Comment: Check the mail log on your server to see if the attempt is being made to send it and the response from the other email server.

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors ? I see no error test in your code, as I don't see any send instruction actually. And if there are no errors, problem could be the processing of your mail by the mail server, or even filtering when receiving that email

Comment: Ok hehe, perhaps it should be `$email->send()` (lower case)?

Comment: tried that - this works fine - http://pastebin.com/UzRtAWV8

Comment: how annoying!! :) any ideas?

Comment: Whats shows `ErrorInfo`? You should try to send a mail from the console and see if it works

Comment: looks like it wanted the AddAttachment part after everything else and just before the Send function

Answer (score 1):

looks like it wanted the AddAttachment part after everything else and just before the Send function